# Checking whether each part of array as numeric

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have an variable that contains the below array. Each part of the array is user submitted how would I go about checking whether each part of the array is an integer value and if it's not then dropping that part of the array?

Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 17 [3] => 5 [4] => 6 [5] => 11 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 15 [10] => 16 [11] => 18 [12] => 10 [13] => 12 [14] => 13 [15] => 14 )

I'm storing the array inside $forums and I've tried array_map("ctype_digit", $forums);

Comment: $forums is where I'm storing the array and I've tried

array_map("ctype_digit", $forums);

Comment: use `array_filter`

Comment: is_numeric($num) with array_filter

Comment: Your question title says "numeric", the description says "integer" and `ctype_digit()` returns true only for *strings consisting entirely of digits* ... Terminology is important, you need to be precise in explaining what you want first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` to get the result array with `'is_numeric'` parameter:

```
$yourArray = Array( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 17 [3] => 5 [4] => 6 [5] => 11 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 15 [10] => 16 [11] => 18 [12] => 10 [13] => 12 [14] => 13 [15] => 14 );
$filtered = array_filter($yourArray, 'is_numeric');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with [`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, 'is_int');
```

You can use like this. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
<?php

$a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,'test',7,8,9];

foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    if(!is_int($value)) {
        unset($a[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and check value array is numeric or not if not then delete that key.

```
foreach($yourArray as $key => $value)
{
   if (!is_numeric($value))
   {
      unset($yourArray[$key]);
   }
}
```